# Bug In ASP.Net With ID Selectors between Css And JQuery For fadeOut Attributes

Tags: jquery, asp.net

During the testing the Asp.Net Web Application I have realized that the JQuery  “fadeIn/Out/Toggle/To attributes are supported in html layer(layout) but not supported to asp: layer(layout) like Panel.

For details you have to follow my below code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs"    Inherits="Animated1._Default" %>

 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
 <head runat="server">
 <title>Untitled Page</title>
 <style type="text/css">
 #pnl1
 {
  width:100px;
  height:150px;
  background-color:red;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:black;
  border-width:3px; 
 }
 </style>
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"   type="text/jscript" ></script>
    <script  type="text/jscript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#<%=Btn.ClientID%>").click(function(){
    $("#<%=pnl1.ClientID %>").fadeOut(3000);});
    });
    </script>

 </head>
 <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnl1" runat="server">
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Button  ID="Btn" runat="server" Text="Mytext" />
    </div>
    </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Now as per above code the asp controls like panel is not support fadeout attribute. Why?.

Now take a look to the same example with html code as below:Just Change the Css ID Selectors and Jquery with above code.

Here is Css/Text Code look like:

```
#div1
{
  width:100px;
  height:150px;
  background-color:red;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:black;
  border-width:3px; 
 }
     //And Jquery Function:
 <script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"   type="text/jscript" ></script>
 <script  type="text/jscript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#Btn").click(function(){
 $("#div1").fadeOut(3000);});
 });
 </script>

 //Rest Of Body Code is here.
  <body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
     <div id="div1"></div>    
       <input type="button" value="fade the div" id="Btn"/>
     </div>
   </form>
  </body>
```

Now the div is support to fadeout attributes and works well.

1.My question is  why the fadeout works at html not with asp:controls?.

2.Is Jquery not support to asp:controls?.

3.Or there are conclusion of ID selectors between Css/JQuery and Asp: Controls?.

And last the solution of above problem. How to handle Selectors of  Asp Controls ID between Css And Jquery as it would works perfect.

Comment: another way is to use parent div for selecting . give it an id like "myDiv" then use "#myDiv input[type=submit]:first" and "#myDiv span:first"

Comment: @mohsen.d, Div is layout(layer) of the web page. It's container of other control hence there is no meaning to try it on div instead it's better to use it on child control like panel and it's my main focus to handle it with panel.

Answer (score 0):

It Should be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#"+"<%=Btn.ClientID%>").click(function(){
$("#"+"<%=pnl1.ClientID %>").fadeOut(3000);});
});
```

Comment: can you try to replace the document.ready body to just alert any string. this is to check whether the event is triggered!

Comment: we can also add 'OnClientClick="JSFunctionName"' attribute to button instead of binding it in document.ready

Comment: it's not wrong, that is an alternate(i think easier) way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It's working there is nothing wrong with the code.

```
<div>
    <div ID="pnl1"></div>
    <input type="Button" value="click" id="Btn"></input>
</div>
```

I have created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gqBWv/

The problem could be the class(css) which you have created.

As you have created css class for ID (#pnl1) and if the id changes at runtime it won't apply on your panel.
So you can use `ClientIdMode="static"` it won't change the id of the controls.

Comment: Shekhar, I am asking about asp:control question and you suggest me html solution. I need to know what is the wrong with above code and solution for the same. here another confusion I have faced that you suggested to "clientIDMode" against run time change ID for css class but it's supplied me the result on panel as I coded to css. Is it possible that as per your suggestion whether it is changed the ID on runtime than is it possible to display the result as I coded?.

Comment: above comment is for css/text

Answer (score 0):

Change your scriptag, it should be like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

also, add this file/link too:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Or simply:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#<%=Btn.ClientID%>").click(function(){
$("#<%=pnl1.ClientID %>").fadeOut(3000);});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry but I can't change the script tag which reference jquery as it is reflect the attribute error like "type" and such is important while you referencing the script query because there are various option regarding the query hence the system confuse to which script allowed or not or there are not any default option for that.

Comment: @MaheshWagh :  I use this `type` while using jQuery, and it works like charm. I dont think it will be any problem, even if it doesnt solve your posted problem. Have you tried this once?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it and it executed with error and no result shown as per coded.